# Webscraper code to download a manga series

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wrote a program to download a manga series fron www.mangapanda.com

Here it is:

```
import os

import requests
from lxml import html

from cleanname import clean_filename

dir_loc = r''
website_url = r'https://www.mangapanda.com'
manga_url = r'https://www.mangapanda.com/one-piece'


def check_url(url):
    url_status = requests.head(url)
    if url_status.status_code < 400:
        return True
    return False


def scrap_chapter_list(url, respose):
    dic = {'chapter': '', 'name': '', 'link': ''}

    # start scrapping
    # soup  = BeautifulSoup(respose.text,'html.parser')
    tree = html.fromstring(respose.content)
    return None


def get_list_of_chapers(url):
    if check_url(url):
        response = requests.get(url).content
        tree = html.fromstring(response)
        path = r'//*/div[@id="chapterlist"]/table[@id="listing"]/tr/td/a'
        res = tree.xpath(path)
        dic = {'chapter': '', 'url': '', 'name': ''}
        result = []
        for i in res:
            dic['chapter'] = i.text
            dic['url'] = website_url + i.attrib['href']
            dic['name'] = i.tail
            result.append(dic)
            dic = {'chapter': '', 'url': '', 'name': ''}
        return result
    return None


def get_page_list(chapter_url):
    res = requests.get(chapter_url).content
    path = r'//*/div[@id="selectpage"]/select[@id="pageMenu"]'
    tree = html.fromstring(res)
    data = tree.xpath(path)[0]
    page_links = ['{}'.format(i.attrib['value']) for i in data]
    return page_links


def get_image_from_page(url):
    """

    :param url:  url of the given manga page eg. /one-piece/1/1
    :return: name of the page(manga name, link to the image file
    """
    dic = {'page_name': '', 'source': ''}
    page_url = r'{}{}'.format(website_url, url)
    res = requests.get(page_url).content
    path = r'//*/img[@id="img"]'
    tree = html.fromstring(res)
    result = tree.xpath(path)
    dic['page_name'], dic['source'] = result[0].attrib['alt'], result[0].attrib['src']
    return dic


def download_image(image_url):
    image_file = requests.get(image_url).content
    return image_file


def save_file(image_file, location, filename, img_format):
    image_loc = os.path.join(location, filename)+img_format
    with open(image_loc, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(image_file)
    return True if os.path.isfile(image_loc) else False


def get_page_details(chapter_url):
    dic = {'page_link': '', 'page_name': '', 'source': ''}
    page_details = get_page_list(chapter_url)
    result = []
    for page in page_details:
        details = get_image_from_page(page)
        dic['page_link'] = page
        dic['page_name'], dic['source'] = details['page_name'], details['source']
        result.append(dic)
        dic = {'page_link': '', 'page_name': '', 'source': ''}
    return result


# if __name__ == '__main__':
#     from .cleanname import clean_filename
manga_url = r'https://www.mangapanda.com/akame-ga-kiru'
storing_location = r'C:\Users\prashra\Pictures\mangascrapper'
manga_name = manga_url.split('/')[-1]
location = os.path.join(storing_location, clean_filename(manga_name))
chapter_list = get_list_of_chapers(manga_url)[:6]

if not os.path.exists(location):
    print('creating the folder {}'.format(manga_name))
    os.makedirs(location)

for chapter in chapter_list:
    name = r'{} {}'.format(chapter['chapter'], chapter['name'])
    chapter_path = os.path.join(location, clean_filename(name))
    print(chapter_path)
    if not os.path.exists(chapter_path):
        os.makedirs(chapter_path)
    chapter_details = get_page_details(chapter['url'])
    for _page in chapter_details:
        name, src = _page['page_name'], _page['source']
        img_format = '.' + src.split('.')[-1]
        print('saving image {} in path {}'.format(name, chapter_path))
        image_data = requests.get(src).content
        save_file(image_data, chapter_path, name, img_format)
```

and in `cleanname.py` file

```
import unicodedata
import string

valid_filename_chars = "-_ %s%s" % (string.ascii_letters, string.digits)
char_limit = 255


def clean_filename(filename, whitelist=valid_filename_chars, replace='_'):
    # replace spaces
    for r in replace:
        filename = filename.replace(r, '_')

    # keep only valid ascii chars
    cleaned_filename = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', filename).encode('ASCII', 'ignore').decode()

    # keep only whitelisted chars
    cleaned_filename = ''.join(c for c in cleaned_filename if c in whitelist)
    if len(cleaned_filename) > char_limit:
        print(
            "Warning, filename truncated because it was over {}. Filenames may no longer be unique".format(char_limit))
    return cleaned_filename[:char_limit]
```

I want to ask :

1. review on this code
2. is it better to convert the code in classes form
3. how to make it scaleable, like to download a chapter only not entire list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just going to focus on your main program, not `cleanname.py`.

- **Import Order**: This one is a personal preference. I like to have my imports ordered alphabetically. You can decide to follow this practice or not.
- **Docstrings**: Docstrings are used to help identify what your method is supposed to do. You should include one in every method you write.
- **Unused variables/methods**: You had a few unused variables and one method. You should remove these to improve the readability of your program, so someone doesn't have to look for 10 minutes (those without a linter, of course) before realizing it's never used in your code.
- **Return expressions**: 
  `if url_status.status_code < 400: return True ... return False` can be reduced to simply `return url_status.status_code < 400`. Returning expressions is much better than returning `True/False`, improves readability greatly.
- **Useless returns**: If you're not expecting to return anything in a method, leave it as it is. Having the line `return None` is redundant, because any method that doesn't return anything automatically returns `None`.
- **Using `f""` over `"".format(...)`**: This one is another preference, but having my strings formatted using `f"..."` looks much cleaner than using `.format`. It allows you to directly implement variables into your strings, rather than concatenating or using the format method.
- **Return/append anonymously**: In many places, you create a dict, change it, append to a list, then reset the dict. That's a lot of steps for adding a dict to a list. You can simply appending an anonymous dict `result.append({ ... })` or `return { ... }`, so you don't need to keep creating/resetting a dict you're only using in that method.
- **Main guard**: You should wrap any code that isn't in a function in a main guard. [Here](//stackoverflow.com/a/5544783) is an answer that provides a deeper and more meaningful explanation.
- **Constant Variable Names**: Variables that are constants should be UPPERCASE.

***Final Code***

```
import os
import requests
from cleanname import clean_filename
from lxml import html

def check_url(url):
    """ Returns the status code being less than 400 """
    return requests.head(url).status_code < 400

def get_list_of_chapters(url):
    """ Returns a list of chapters from the specified `url` """
    if check_url(url):
        response = requests.get(url).content
        tree = html.fromstring(response)
        path = r'//*/div[@id="chapterlist"]/table[@id="listing"]/tr/td/a'
        res = tree.xpath(path)
        result = []
        for i in res:
            result.append({
                'chapter': i.text,
                'url': WEBSITE_URL + i.attrib['href'],
                'name': i.tail
            })
        return result
    return None


def get_page_list(chapter_url):
    """ Returns a list of link to the page on `chapter_url` """
    res = requests.get(chapter_url).content
    path = r'//*/div[@id="selectpage"]/select[@id="pageMenu"]'
    tree = html.fromstring(res)
    data = tree.xpath(path)[0]
    page_links = [f"{i.attrib['value']}" for i in data]
    return page_links

def get_image_from_page(url):
    """ Gets the image from `url` """
    page_url = f"{WEBSITE_URL}{url}"
    res = requests.get(page_url).content
    path = r'//*/img[@id="img"]'
    tree = html.fromstring(res)
    result = tree.xpath(path)
    return {
        'page_name': result[0].attrib['alt'],
        'source': result[0].attrib['src']
    }


def download_image(image_url):
    """ Downloads image from `image_url` """
    return requests.get(image_url).content


def save_file(image_file, save_location, filename, save_img_format):
    """ Saves the `image_file` to `location` with the name `filename` """
    image_loc = os.path.join(save_location, filename) + save_img_format
    with open(image_loc, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(image_file)
    return os.path.isfile(image_loc)


def get_page_details(chapter_url):
    """ Gets the details about the page """
    page_details = get_page_list(chapter_url)
    result = []
    for page in page_details:
        details = get_image_from_page(page)
        result.append({
            'page_link': page,
            'page_name': details['page_name'],
            'source': details['source']
        })
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':

    DIR_LOC = r''
    WEBSITE_URL = r'https://www.mangapanda.com'
    MANGA_URL = r'https://www.mangapanda.com/one-piece'

    MANGA_URL = r'https://www.mangapanda.com/akame-ga-kiru'
    STORING_LOCATION = r'C:\Users\prashra\Pictures\mangascrapper'
    MANGA_NAME = MANGA_URL.split('/')[-1]
    LOCATION = os.path.join(STORING_LOCATION, clean_filename(MANGA_NAME))
    CHAPTER_LIST = get_list_of_chapters(MANGA_URL)[:6]

    if not os.path.exists(LOCATION):
        print(f"Creating folder: {MANGA_NAME}")
        os.makedirs(LOCATION)

    for chapter in CHAPTER_LIST:
        name = rf"{chapter['chapter']}{chapter['name']}"
        chapter_path = os.path.join(LOCATION, clean_filename(name))
        print(chapter_path)
        if not os.path.exists(chapter_path):
            os.makedirs(chapter_path)
        chapter_details = get_page_details(chapter['url'])
        for _page in chapter_details:
            name, src = _page['page_name'], _page['source']
            img_format = f".{src.split('.')[-1]}"
            print(f"Saving image {name} in path {chapter_path}")
            image_data = requests.get(src).content
            save_file(image_data, chapter_path, name, img_format)
```

Comment: thanks for the valubable feedback, I like the way you explain and all the points you mentioned, will consider all points and implement it in the code, just disagreeing of using "f" over `''.format()` part, i find it more readable and more customisable , will stick to this part , rest i like they way you did `inline` checking of url status and overocome the headache of creating new dict everytime